# 47 GB of 64 GB Ram full after new install

Tags: 16.04, server, ram

after a fresh installation Ubuntu 16.04 Server no programs installed it shows that a lot of ram is used:

```
          total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:      64392        44549        2650        3045       17192       16130

Swap:         10239           0       10239
```

Result of `sudo apt-get install htop -y`:

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Results of `df`:

```
Filesystem   1K-blocks    Used     Available    Use%     Mounted on 
/dev/md2     245760000    2551808  243208192    1%       / 
none         492          0        492          0%       /dev 
cgroup_root  10240        0        10240        0%       /sys/fs/cgroup   
tmpfs        32968876     0        32968876     0%       /dev/shm 
tmpfs        32968876     8276     32960600     1%       /run 
tmpfs        5120         0        5120         0%       /run/lock
```

Results of `sudo apt-get update and sudo apt-get upgrade and reboot`:

```
Trigger for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.5) werden verarbeitet ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
WARNING: missing /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64
Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64: No such file or directory
depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_wJ8Kyu/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.order: No such file or directory
depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_wJ8Kyu/lib/modules/3.16.0-4-amd64/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
```

And after Reboot nothing changed.

I don't have seen this on any other servers I had. 
I don't think its normal, so anyone have a idea?

Thanks

Comment: Try using htop and see graphically where everything is being distributed.
`sudo apt-get install htop -y`

Comment: Thanks i have made a screenshot: http://prntscr.com/dkgwus

Comment: Rather than do `htop` do `df` (disk usage) and paste the result.

Comment: here you go: Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/md2        245760000  2551808  243208192  1% /
none                 492         0       492   0% /dev
cgroup_root        10240         0     10240   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           32968876         0  32968876   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           32968876      8276  32960600   1% /run
tmpfs               5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock

Comment: with the `htop` the results change so look to see what is using `CPU%` and `MEM%` and let us know

Comment: with the `htop` the results change so look to see what process is using `CPU%` and `MEM%` in high percentages and let us know

Comment: I sorted by CPU% and MEM% and watched 8 mins. but nothing changed in htop, its always on 0.0%.

Comment: And my CPU cores are every 10 seconds on 20%

Comment: Try doing `sudo apt-get update`, `sudo apt-get upgrade -y`, and then restart.

Comment: Done see start post

Comment: Why your `RAM` is so big can't say why, but the _usage_ is normal as I have checked mine and my usage is _75%_ of 8gb. And from your post images you can see that the usage is ok. Perhaps your _swap_ size should be more (IMO).

Comment: Maybe [this article](https://linux-mm.org/Low_On_Memory) from the developers may help to understand what eats up your memory.

Comment: Did you see http://www.linuxatemyram.com/ ?

Answer (score -1):

--edit--
Please post the contents of "/etc/fstab" - we may find the answer there...

It looks like you may have somehow loaded the SWAP file and tmpfs into main memory.
Try temporarily turning off the swap file "swapoff -a" and see if it drops by 10GB.

Comment: There is no evidence that a swap file is even being used, and the whole point of `tmpfs` is to use RAM.

Comment: "Swap:         10239           0       10239"

Comment: and "Swp 0K/10.00G" from htop jpg

Comment: Swap is almost universally set up to use a disk partition, not a file. This places it on squarely on disk, not in RAM.

Comment: What harm would trying "swapoff -a" to see if it changes memory usage do? You rule it our simply because it shouldn't do that... Isn't that part of the symptoms - that the system it isn't doing what is expected?

Comment: I didn't say it shouldn't do that. I said that your solutions were incredibly unlikely (swap being stored in RAM) and impossible (moving `tmpfs` out of RAM). These steps are not anywhere close to the beginning of any decent troubleshooting method. Turning swap off can also lead to significant problems like the system randomly killing applications if the system needs swap, so it's both a waste of time to try it first and potentially dangerous.